# Can't get table navigation to resize just in mobile while the rest of the website does

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On mobile, the navigation I have at the top of my website won't resize, and scale down, with the width of the mobile screen. Instead, the width stays constant. Everything else, including images and text, properly resizes.

My website is: https://whereshouldieat.ie/

The table's style is as follows:

```
 <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
```

However, even with its width set to 100%, it does not scale down for mobile devices.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<!-- if the map is being displayed i.e. homepage -->
        <div id="map-wrapper">
        <div id="map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"><div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px;"><div tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;) 8 8, default;"><div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 252px; top: 173px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 252px; top: 429px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 252px; top: -83px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -4px; top: 173px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -4px; top: -83px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -4px; top: 429px;"></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 252px; top: 173px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15812!3i10621!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=25370" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 252px; top: 429px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15812!3i10622!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=126878" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -4px; top: 173px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15811!3i10621!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=16746" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -4px; top: -83px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15811!3i10620!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=46309" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: -4px; top: 429px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15811!3i10622!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=118254" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 252px; top: -83px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i15!2i15812!3i10620!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i386079896!3m14!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e68!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!12m4!1e26!2m2!1sstyles!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!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=54933" draggable="false" alt="" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-pbc" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0;"><p class="gm-style-pbt"></p></div><div style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div></div></div><div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.348579,-6.28726&amp;z=15&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"><div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white5_hdpi.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></a></div><div style="background-color: white; padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 148px; position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 160px;"><div style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 16px;">Map Data</div><div style="font-size: 13px;">Map data ©2017 Google</div><div style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 80px; bottom: 0px; width: 134px;"><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: none;">Map Data</a><span style="">Map data ©2017 Google</span></div></div></div><div class="gmnoscreen" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); direction: ltr; text-align: right; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">Map data ©2017 Google</div></div><div class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc" draggable="false" style="z-index: 1000001; user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Terms of Use</a></div></div><div style="cursor: pointer; width: 25px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; display: none; margin: 10px 14px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/sv9.png" draggable="false" class="gm-fullscreen-control" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -86px; width: 164px; height: 175px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; display: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a target="_new" title="Report errors in the road map or imagery to Google" href="https://www.google.com/maps/@53.348579,-6.2872604,15z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&amp;rapsrc=apiv3" style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; position: relative;">Report a map error</a></div></div></div></div></div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div id="load" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="location">Location</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="location-choices">
                    <td class="choice1"><a href="#" class="choice1 btn">Near Me</a></td>
                    <td class="choice2"><a href="#" class="choice1 btn">Choose Location</a></td>
                    <td class="choice3"><a href="#" class="choice3 btn">Anywhere</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>           
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-fixed-top" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="https://whereshouldieat.ie/" class="header-button map">What to Eat</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="https://whereshouldieat.ie/#about" class="header-button map">About</a>
                </li>
                <!-- Logo -->
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://whereshouldieat.ie/" title="Where Should I Eat?">
                        <img id="navbar-logo" src="assets/img/logo/wsiewhite.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="https://whereshouldieat.ie/#contact" class="header-button map">Contact</a>
                </li><li class="changepage" data-toggle="changepage" data-target="#myModal">
                    <a href="https://whereshouldieat.ie/content/" class="header-button map">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are using on the overlay are a large fixed size, which causes the table cells to stretch.

Change your font sizes to use a scalable measure like `vw`, `em`, `%` etc.

Comment: I say this as someone who is confused. Aren't the rest of my fonts defined in the same way, like none of the others have vw, em or %

Comment: Yes, but your table cell width is dependent on the content. You could add `max-width` to the table cells to prevent the undesired growth as well, but responsive text sizing is generally a better solution.

Comment: I've changed the text to be em now, but still it goes too far right on the mobile device, do you know why, I understand I'm probably being thick here, but I didn't write this code originally

Comment: You have to find the right values. The page also uses fixed pixel values for the `padding`, which has a disproportional effect when the screen is narrow.

The page uses bootstrap, which has breakpoints for small screen handling. Change the `font-size` for only mobile devices might be an easier way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Some third party software, including Google Maps and Google Custom Search Engine, conflict with Bootstrap due to * { box-sizing: border-box; }, a rule which makes it so padding does not affect the final computed width of an element. Learn more about box model and sizing at CSS Tricks https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Depending on the context, you may override as-needed (Option 1) or reset the box-sizing for entire regions (Option 2).

```
/* Box-sizing resets
 *
 * Reset individual elements or override regions to avoid conflicts due to
 * global box model settings of Bootstrap. Two options, individual overrides and
 * region resets, are available as plain CSS and uncompiled Less formats.
 */

/* Option 1A: Override a single element's box model via CSS */
.element {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* Option 1B: Override a single element's box model by using a Bootstrap Less mixin */
.element {
  .box-sizing(content-box);
}

/* Option 2A: Reset an entire region via CSS */
.reset-box-sizing,
.reset-box-sizing *,
.reset-box-sizing *:before,
.reset-box-sizing *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* Option 2B: Reset an entire region with a custom Less mixin */
.reset-box-sizing {
  &,
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    .box-sizing(content-box);
  }
}
.element {
  .reset-box-sizing();
}

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Hi I currently have this in my bootstrap for it, but it doesn't seem to work

*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

As I think something in the overlay is overridding it